# Which way to earn Battle Points earns the most per hour?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Currently there are 3 ways to earn BP. You have Battle Test, Battle Maison, and Super Battle Maison. Which one will earn the most amount of Battle Points per hour (Assume that a well built team is being used for this)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Super Battle Maison battles are the best because of the least downtime, assuming you can somewhat consistently beat them up to and beyond round 20.

Doing the regular Battle Maison fights will require you to start over repeatedly, and half the fights will only earn you a single BP. [In Super Battles you'll earn 2 points for the first 10 rounds then 1 extra BP per round after the next 10 rounds, up to a maximum of 7 after 51 rounds.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Maison) Due to the Battle Maison characters [quite literally cheating](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67674496) it can be hard to keep up that momentum though.

It does somewhat depend how far you can go; if the regular battles are easy but you die in the first 10 or so battles of Super Battle Maison, it's better to do regular battles just for the consistent earn and the 20 BP payout at the (relatively easy) Battle Chatelaine fight at round 20. 20 rounds of normal battle earn you 48 BP thanks to the 20 BP bonus, you'll only come out ahead in Super Battles after round 20, but after that it's a solidly better earn rate. However if you LOSE the 20th round in Normal Battles, you lose almost half your possible earn.

Battle institute is just...bad, unless there's some insane payout for doing perfectly somehow. I've found it pretty pointless myself, but I can't find the exact payouts in order to completely disprove it. I just know that winning all rounds handily still isn't quite enough for it to be faster than Super Battles in Battle Maison.

Comment: In the Battle Insituite, all I was able to find is that a 7 star run gets 15 BP and a PP UP. Also, why do all of the Battle Point earning places have to cheat? The last battle of Super Battle Maison (and sometimes the Battle Institute) get Legendaries.

Comment: @ShadowZorgon well the Battle Institute and Battle Masion Normal Battles don't cheat very much. But basically all of my Super Battle runs have been ruined by cheating AI. It's a shame because they'd be really fun if they'd just cut down on the dialog/out of battle time and make them NOT CHEAT.

Comment: Just want to point out that the Battle Maison characters do not cheat. Bad luck is always overplayed. If they're cheating, then my Ferrothorn taking out a Mega Charizard after avoiding all of its Fire Blasts (half through Protect, half through just straight-up evading) is the biggest cheater of all. For example in that link you posted, someone is in disbelief of a Liepard outspeeding their Blaziken... clearly has never heard of the Prankster ability. Seriously. But that said, the game does try to generate teams that counter your team over time, which makes sense since they *are* spectators.

Comment: Another point is that all the Legendaries that are used by the Maison? YOU CAN USE THEM TOO! Yes, you can PokéBank an Entei, teach it Sacred Fire, and cremate your opponents with it!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yeah, thanks to pokemon bank Maison is a LITTLE less broken compared to when players couldn't possible have those same pokemon, but there are a few dozen independent reports of Battle Maison cheating, such as http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/490580-confirmation-that-the-battle-maison-is-cheating I'm prreeetty sure it cheats. It's a classic, cheap way to make AI hard, after all.

Comment: @BenBrocka Considering that's completely impossible within the code of the game (not to mention, what happens if you were to use Thief on such a "cheat"), I find it much more likely that they were simply mistaken about which Pokémon had the White Herb.